# How to scrape the table from website with python-scrape h4 information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to scrape table with python, and I would like to scrape the table of crime rates:
the packages I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

here is my code:
loading empty array

```
data = []
page = requests.get("http://www.city-data.com/city/Belmont-Massachusetts.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
```

identify table we want to scrape

```
table = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"table tabBlue tblsort tblsticky sortable"})
```

loop through table, grab each of the 13 columns shown

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('h4').get_text()
    if len(cols) == 13:
        data.append((cols[0].text.strip(), cols[1].text.strip(), cols[2].text.strip(), cols[3].text.strip(),cols[4].text.strip(),cols[5].text.strip(),cols[6].text.strip(),cols[7].text.strip(),cols[8].text.strip(),cols[9].text.strip(),cols[10].text.strip(),cols[11].text.strip(),cols[12].text.strip(),cols[13].text.strip()))
except: pass 


data = np.asarray(data)
len(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

I use Mac os, python 3
however, in the last I got an empty list. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

The error I got I am guessing that because I had problem scrape h4 information(the header of the table is in the h4 area..)

Answer (score 0):

I did scraping like this.

```
# yes, you identified the right table
right_table=soup.find('table', {"class":'table tabBlue tblsort tblsticky sortable'})

rows = right_table.findAll("tr")

# header attributes of the table
header = [th.text.rstrip() for th in rows[0].find_all('th')]

# data
lst_data = []
for row in rows[1:]:
            data = [d.text.rstrip() for d in row.find_all('td')]
            lst_data.append(data)

# your expected result
df = pd.DataFrame(lst_data, columns=header)
print(df)
```

Happy scraping !

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Yes, still have a lot to learn in scraping